# referring terms in the glossary

Tags: glossaries, best-practices

I am using LaTeX  to  write  my  thesis.   To define new terms and its definition, I have used the glossary as separate chapter at the end of thesis.  I use `\gls` command to refer the terms defined in the glossary.

**I have a question related to referring the terms in glossary:**

Should  I  refer terms defined in the glossary per chapter in the whole thesis?

**OR**

Should I refer the terms only once in the whole thesis?

The problem with the latter approach is that  if  reviewers skip the chapter, where I refer the terms, they will never understand the terms and  its meaning properly.

Can you please advise me on the proper place of  referring the terms defined in the glossary?

Comment: This depends very much on the subject area and the conventions used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this depends very much on your thesis.

If you are writing something, where skipping chapters has to be expected (like a handbook), you should put each glossary at the end of the chapters. In the most common case, one glossary at the end will be enough. When someone does not know the meaning of something, he will always know, where to look. If you use the `\gls{...}` command, just use it every time, the word appears. The word will then serve as a hyper-link.

If you are using first appearance styles like for acronyms (e.g. "... CD (compact disk)...", you can reset the counter of appearances for each chapter or part. If you do so, every `\gls{CD}` in the chapter will print "CD" and the first appearance in the new chapter will print again as "CD (compact disk)". If you would like this approach, see the manual of the package `glossaries`. It has a beginners guide as well.

Of course you may always write "(s. glossary)" or "\footnote{explanation of this word}" at the first use in a new chapter. It is not forbidden to communicate with the reviewers and to help them find their information.

For more information, you have to show us, how an entry with glossary and one without looks in your thesis (link, color, "(...)", `\footnote{...}`) so that we are able to help you.